# how can i pass a parameters to a function to get current Style

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Good day, 
I wonder how to get currentStyle in IE, passing parameters to an function argument like this:

```
function test(el,value){
  return document.getElementById(el).currentStyle[value];
}
```

if i'd use a similar function to get Style from Firefox, Chrome and so on, it would result.

using a function like this:

```
function test(el,value){
  return getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(obj))[value];
}
```

, where value is the element property like backgroundColor, i.e:

```
alert(test('ObjectId','backgroundColor'));
```

....
it would return backgroundColor in FF, Chrome.. but not in Internet Explorer

What r possibles solutions..?

Thnx..

please i'm not looking for a jQuery soluction...

Comment: Your script snippet using currentStyle should work in IE.  Is it not working?

Comment: Why don't you want to use jquery? If they have answered the question for you, check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Here what I use to retrieve a style property value

```
function getStyle(el,sProp,toInt){
    var elem = el;
    if (elem.currentStyle) {
       return toInt 
              ? parseInt(elem.currentStyle[sProp],10) 
              : elem.currentStyle[sProp] || 0;
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var compStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null)[sProp];
        return toInt ? parseInt(compStyle,10) : compStyle || 0;
    }
    return String(elem.style[sProp]||0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is (sadly) very complex.

I have written a browser independent resolver but I can't share it with you.

Unless you are writing your own framework I have to ask, why do you want to be able to resolve everything?
Is there a specific property (or some properties) you want? Because that could be a lot easier.

If you just want the background color then .style.backgroundColor is probably sufficient.

Also, there is a bug in your example script:

```
alert(test('ObjectId'),'backgroundColor');
```

Should be:

```
alert(test('ObjectId','backgroundColor'));
```

Not the first time I made the same mistake ;) - took me half a day to find it

Comment: Objective is to retrieve unknow properties until the function be called, but the problem in this function that i wrote here that is a sketch to specify my concern, is that Internet explorer parses the argument "value" as unknow property, namely, before i pass the parameter it parses currentStyle[value]. It happens when meta content http-equiv="x-ua-compatibility" is set to "IE=EmulateIE8", <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>, so, this way you can try it by yourself. By the way, i'm writing my own framework. Thank you.